# How do I define a method on one line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is `def greet; puts "hello"; end` the only way to define a method on one line in Ruby?

Comment: As you can see from the answers, it's possible to define a method different ways on a single line, but the question is, should you? Any definition should be written in a way that is clear and clean for maintenance and readability reasons, so if the single-line becomes unwieldy or confusing then spread it out. Some languages seem to encourage terse coding as a way of being code-studly, but Ruby coding style encourages elegance, readability and maintainability above studliness. Accomplish the first three and we will bow to you.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can avoid the need to use semicolons if you use parentheses:

```
def hello() :hello end
```

Comment: This is longer than using semicolons...?

Comment: @ApollyssupportsMonica if yoou read his question he already used semi-colons, so he clearly wanted an ALTERNATIVE approach :)

Answer (score 99):

### No Single-line Methods

From [rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-single-line-methods](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-single-line-methods):

> Avoid single-line methods.   Although they are somewhat popular in the
> wild, there are a few peculiarities about their definition syntax that
> make their use undesirable. At any rate - **there should be no more
> than one expression in a single-line method**.
>
> NOTE: Ruby 3 introduced an alternative syntax for single-line method
> definitions, that's discussed in the next section of the guide.

```rb
# bad
def too_much; something; something_else; end

# okish - notice that the first ; is required
def no_braces_method; body end

# okish - notice that the second ; is optional
def no_braces_method; body; end

# okish - valid syntax, but no ; makes it kind of hard to read
def some_method() body end

# good
def some_method
  body
end
```

> One exception to the rule are empty-body methods.

```rb
# good
def no_op; end
```

### Endless Methods

From [rubocop/ruby-style-guide#endless-methods](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#endless-methods):

> Only use Ruby 3.0's endless method definitions with a single line
> body.  Ideally, such method definitions should be both simple (a
> single expression) and free of side effects.
>
> NOTE: It's important to understand that this guideline doesn't
> contradict the previous one. We still caution against the use of
> single-line method definitions, but if such methods are to be used,
> prefer endless methods.

```rb
# bad
def fib(x) = if x < 2
  x
else
  fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
end

# good
def the_answer = 42
def get_x = @x
def square(x) = x * x

# Not (so) good: has side effect
def set_x(x) = (@x = x)
def print_foo = puts("foo")
```

---

P.S.: Just to give an up-to-date full answer.

Answer (score 41):

```
def add a,b; a+b end
```

The semicolon is the inline statement terminator for Ruby

Or you can use the `define_method` method. (Edit: This one's deprecated in ruby 1.9)

```
define_method(:add) {|a,b| a+b }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be deprecated in Ruby 2+

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 3.0.0 [adds "endless" definitions](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#endless-method-definition) for methods with exactly one statement:

```
def greet = puts("hello")
```

Note that the one-statement limitation means that this **can't** be written as:

```
# NOT ALLOWED
def greet = puts "hello"

SyntaxError: unexpected string literal, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
def greet = puts "hello"
                 ^
```

It seems that this change was intended to either [encourage the use of one-line methods](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#endless-method-definition) or adjust to the reality that they are very common but hard to read -- ["this kind of simple method definition [is estimated to] account for 24% of the entire method definitions" of the `ruby/ruby` code base](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16746).

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
define_method(:greet) { puts 'hello' }
```

May be used if you don't want to enter new scope for method while defining it.

Comment: NoMethodError: private method `define_method' called for Object:Class in Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: `define_method` has been "privatized" in Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way:

```
def greet() return 'Hello' end
```

Comment: In Ruby, the return value of a method is the value returned by the last statement. You don't need the `return` here since it's not a guard clause.

Comment: Upvoted because, although it is not _needed_, the `return` can add readability for those less versed in (or familiar with) Ruby. It's one of those [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) things...